# How to add the value passed in the view to a href attribute in a pug view

Tags: node.js, pug

Here is the function passing the data to the view

I don't understand what i am doing wrong that i receive an error at this line when the view is loaded

`a(href="https://imdb.com/title/"+${m.ids.imdb})`

```
function displayPopularMovies(res){
var pageData={
  title:"Popular",
  movies: null
};
  axios(
{
  url:"/movies/popular",
  baseURL:trakt,
  method:"get",
  headers:{
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
    "trakt-api-version":2,
    "trakt-api-key":process.env.TRAKT_CLIENT_ID
  },
  params: { page: 1,limit:15 }

}
  ).then(function (response){

    pageData.movies=response.data;
    res.render("popular",pageData);
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

here is the code for popular.pug

```
extends layout

block layout-content
  h1 Popular movies
  table
   each m in movies
    tr
      td
        a(href="https://imdb.com/title/"+${m.ids.imdb})
         p #{m.title}
      td
        p #{m.year}
```

Comment: Could you share information on what error you receive?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your indentation is off, which is critical in pug. Can you try the following?

```
extends layout

block layout-content
  h1 Popular movies
  table
    each m in movies
      tr
        td
          a(href=`https://imdb.com/title/${m.ids.imdb}`)
          p #{m.title}
        td
          p #{m.year}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this for you string interpolation?

```
      - var url = `https://www.imdb.com/title/${m.ids.imdb}`
      a(href=url) #{m.title}
```